# Excel Conditional Formatting - IF this copy this cell

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have a need to do some conditional formatting based off other cells.

Basically I need it to do:

If cell contains yes, use the formatting of cell A1
If cell contains no, use the formatting of cell B2

Comment: See this question: http://superuser.com/questions/98755/excel-copy-cell-formatting-in-equation

Comment: Thanks, however this simply states I need VBA but no more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do this by adding a reference cell

```
=IF(SearchMultipleTbl($B21,E$20,Overview!$C$2:$XY$82)="Yes",VLOOKUP(E$20,Overview!$C$3:$E$961,3,FALSE)="On Hold",FALSE)
```

The SearchMultipleTbl looks for the answer, if it is yes it uses the Vlookup of a reference cell

Answer (score -1):

I don't know exactly what you are looking for but this should help.

```
=IF(A2="yes","true","false")
```

If A2 is yes then use the first condition, otherwise the second.

Hope this helps.